# From Log value to Exponential value, huge Distortion for prediction of machine learning algorithm

Tags: algorithm, function, math, optimization, machine-learning

I build a machine learning algorithms to predict Y' value. For this, I used Log value of Y for data scaling. 
As I got the predicted Y' and actual Y value, I have to convert Log value of Y&Y' to Exponential value.

**BUT, there was so huge distortion from the values over exp7 (=ln1098)... It makes a lot of MSE(error).**

**How can I avoid this huge distortion??** (Generally, I need to get values over 1000)

Thanks!!

Comment: Taking the log of the dependent variable makes sense if you have multiplicative noise (i.e. noise is proportional to the size of the dependent variable). If that's not the case, then don't do that. Normalizing to mean 0 and variance 1 (i.e. subtract mean and divide by standard deviation) can help avoid numerical problems, maybe you can try that. You might get more helpful responses at stats.stackexchange.com or maybe datascience.stackexchangecom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For this, I used Log value of Y for data scaling.
>   Not for scaling, but to make target variable distribution normal.

If your MSE arises when real target value arises too - it means that the model simply can't fit enough on big values. Usually it can be solved by cleaning data (removing outliers). Or take another ML-model.

**UPDATE**
You can run KFold and for each fold calculate MSE/MAE between predicted and real values. Then take big errors and take a look which parameters/features this cases have.

You can eliminate cases with big errors, but it's usually dangerous.

In general bad fit on big values mean that you did not remove outliers from your original dataset. Plot histograms and scatter plots and make sure that you don't have them.

Check categorical variables: maybe you have small values (<=5%). If so, group them.

Or you need to create 2 models: one for small values, one for big ones.

Comment: Thanks. ML model has a good fitness on Log value. If so, how can I find outliers of big values that cause distortion?

Comment: I updated my answer.